# Simulate mouse click or enter key press on non-native element

Tags: angular

I am using a third party non-native Angular 2 calendar component called: mydatepicker

It shows as this when implemented on the form:

[image]

This is how I added it to HTML:

```
<my-date-picker #datePickerBox 
    [options]="myDatePickerOptions">
</my-date-picker>
```

I need to programatically invoke the calendar window, which under normal circumstances opens without any issues (if I use a mouse and click the icon or press the enter key when focused on the my-date-picker element).

BTW. this is what it looks like when the icon is clicked: 
[image]

My problem is that users of my app also need to open the calendar window by pressing the F9 key and I don't know how to go about it.

This is the code I have so far.

```
@ViewChild('datePickerBox') datePickerBox:ElementRef;
constructor(private renderer:Renderer) {}

f9KeyOnPartialDateComponent(event): void {
 if(event.keyCode === 120) {
  let mouseclick = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
  setTimeout(() => {      
  this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.datePickerBox.nativeElement,
  'dispatchEvent', [mouseclick]); }, 500);
 }
}
```

This works if "#datePickerBox" is placed on a native element such as the input field, but doesn't work when I place it on the `<my-date-picker>`. I get:

[image]

Is it that click, focus and other events are available only on native elements?
Any way to open the calendar windows of this component by using Angular 2?

**UPDATE:**
A new version 1.6.4 of mydatepicker allows opening of the component programmatically: https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker/wiki/Open-selector-with-selector-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `@ViewChild` on a custom element, it will return the `Component` instance. This instance does not have the `nativeElement` property.

**Option #1**

You should change your `@ViewChild` call that it returns the `ElementRef` and not the component, although I'm not entirely positive this will work:

```
@ViewChild('datePickerBox', {read: ElementRef}) 
datePickerBox:ElementRef;
```

**Option #2**

If option 1 doesn't work, you should update your `MyDatePickerComponent` to have this in the constructor:

```
constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef){}
```

You can then use the renderer like this:

```
this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.datePickerBox.elementRef.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [mouseclick]);
```

And change your `@ViewChild` to:

```
@ViewChild('datePickerBox') 
datePickerBox: MyDatePickerComponent;
```

**Option #3**

If that custom component of yours has a `toggleDatePicker` method (or anything close to it), you better just call that method instead of messing around with events. Much cleaner, and nicer. As I told you, `@ViewChild` will return the component instance, so all you have to do is:

```
@ViewChild('datePickerBox') 
datePickerBox: MyDatePickerComponent;


f9KeyOnPartialDateComponent(event): void {
  if(event.keyCode === 120) {
     this.datePickerBox.toggleDatePicker();
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't manage yet, but in mean time author of the component released a new version that allows opening of the component programmatically. As per him, it wasn't possible until it was implemented: https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker/wiki/Open-selector-programmatically

Comment: So I was close with my toggleDatePicker :D